# Cascading issue in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012

I have SSRS report in which for parameter I have done the cascading, like I am having country parameter and state parameter, so if I select only the country 'US' then the state parameter is giving me only the states of 'US' and all those states are automatically getting selected but now if I select the 'All' in the Country parameter then in dropdown of states all the states are coming(including that of 'US' and other countries) but they are not getting automatically selected. How to make them automatically selected?

Comment: I assume you have the default values to the same dataset as your available values. Unfortunately, as far as I know, the default values only get filled once. There are several post on SO about this issue. There is an option in the parameter properties "Always Refresh" but even setting this on seems to have no impact.

Comment: Exactly
So is there any option to get the filters in default condition, like if i click on a particular button it resets my all the filters to default condition

Comment: As far as I know, not without refreshing the page.